# Errors when system in idle Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a **Laravel** project. Front end I am done with **Vuejs**. Its working good.

The problem is:

When the system is in idle for some times, and when click any link I got the some console errors and the system is not loading data.
That is the *vuejs axios* gives the error

```
POST http://localhost:8000//api/v1/auth/channels/listchannels 400 (Bad Request)
GET http://localhost:8000//api/v1/auth/user 400 (Bad Request) 
POST http://localhost:8000//api/v1/auth/sources/listsources 400 (Bad Request)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (app.js:1812)
    at settle (app.js:1975)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:1345)
```

When I refresh the page the errors are gone and its working good.

Why this happened? Is there any *autoload* functions there in *vuejs* to avoid the issue?

Comment: it seems you are calling this api with bad Request, can you check  networkk tab what is payload to this api may be that is causing  error

Comment: @KamleshPaul, in network tab its showing `{error: "Unauthorized"}
error: "Unauthorized"` for all requests

Comment: yeah it correct you have to add auth header to all of your route